# How to setup multiple gemfire/geode WAN clusters on one machine for testing?

Tags: gemfire, geode

What's needed to run multiple gemfire/geode clusters on one machine?  I'm trying to test using WAN gateways locally, before setting it up on servers.

I have one cluster (i.e. gemfire.distributed-system-id=1) up and running with one locator and one server.

I am trying to setup a second cluster (i.e. gemfire.distributed-system-id=2), but receive the following error when attempting to connect to the locator in cluster 2:

> Exception caused JMX Manager startup to fail because: 'HTTP service
>   failed to start'

I assume the error is due to a JMX Manager already running in cluster 1, so I'm guessing I need to start a second JMX Manager on a different port in cluster 2.  Is this a correct assumption?  If so, how do I setup the second JMX Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, the exception is being thrown because the first members started some services (`PULSE`, `jmx-manager`, etc.) using the default ports already

You basically want to make sure the properties `http-service-port` and `jmx-manager-port` (non an extensive list, there are other properties you need to look at), are different in the second cluster.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Setting 'http-service-port' and 'jmx-manager-port' differently for the locators in the different clusters was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.